# How soon can I expect to get a weapon/skill that can attack multiple enemies and not consume MP?

Tags: bravely-default

I'm the kind of player who doesn't mind grinding sessions to get levels to prepare me for moving forward in games... as long as the game makes that easier to accomplish and doesn't make it a chore.  This game makes grinding very easy to do with the ability to increase encounter rate, auto-attacks and braving which I love.  I'm already at level ~39 and just reached the beginning of chapter 2.  And all I do is leave the encounter rate at +100% and auto-attack braving 4 times using plain attacks.  There's nothing for me to monitor so this is perfect for how I want to play.

I noticed that I haven't obtained the last 3 combat bonuses (bonuses related to killing multiple enemies in a single attack) yet due to my play style but I want to start taking advantage of that.  However, that would mean that I would need to use attacks that can attack multiple enemies always.  But that poses problems for my style of play:

- So far, every magic spell or skill that I've come across that can target multiple enemies require MP.
- Special attacks that can target multiple enemies cannot be used always. I have to build up the attack before I can use it.

By requiring MP, I am forced to keep my MP replenished.  That's not something I necessarily want to have to worry about if I'm wandering around.  And it's just not practical waiting for a special attack to be usable.  It's also awkward setting up auto-attacks for special skills since they can only be used once at a time.

**When can I expect to get a weapon or skill that can attack multiple enemies and not consume MP? (if any)**

If it means getting a particular job at a particular level or certain item, I can rush to that point in the game and be happy with that.  If no such weapon or skills exist, it's not the end of the world, I'd just like to know if any do exist, then I can make adjustments to how I play.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The earliest class able to attack multiple enemies without using MP is the Valkyrie, obtained in Chapter 2. Their initial skill is Crescent Moon, which deals conventional damage to all enemies and costs 1 BP.

Comment: Ooh, that would be perfect. Is that mid-chapter 2? Later? Earlier?

Comment: Valkyrie is obtained in a side-quest after the Flower Festival.

Comment: +1 for a clear, concise answer and for clarifying about when to get the asterisk. Just remember: if you're going to use Crescent Moon for grinding (capital idea, by the way), note the move's BP cost, as mentioned in the original answer. If you have all four characters spam that ability from the start, they'll only be able to Brave once, for 8 moves total, since they'd hit -3 BP if they use it both times. Be sure you can do enough damage with those eight strikes to kill all enemies in your grinding location of choice, or you may wind up taking four turns worth of pain afterward.